# Introductory or Primer text on Economics?

Tags: financial-economics, international-economics, economic-terms, energy-economics, stock-market

I've been meaning to learn more about economics, and am looking for an introductory text or a primer on the topic.

I've already taken a subject on this back in high school, but I guess what I'm looking for is more on breadth. Something that'll introduce me to the things that I should know if I am to read an article on the news concerning updates on the world's economy and the local market.

I just want to get into being updated on such things. And thought of asking because maybe you guys who're more experienced can point me to the right direction instead of me reading about on different things, when in fact there are better references.

I'm a computer engineering undergrad, and my reason for wanting to learn about this is to be updated about the economy (it interests me), and because I want to get into stocks and forex eventually. I've already been reading books and articles on stocks, but I guess I'm just looking for something comprehensive and structured.

So a recommended text on stocks or forex would be nice too! Something on terms and the likes I guess :D same for the references I'm looking for concerning economics. Thanks a lot for the help!

My interest on the topic also concerns my intention to eventually focus on a field regarding energy consumption, the smart grid and the likes, and environmental sustainability.

So being able to understand and gain a working knowledge about economics seems like something that I should know.

Comment: For readings on smart grid technology and the economic issues, you might want to find a list of short readings rather than a book. You might do well by reaching out to an academic who works in that particular area, like Lynne Kiesling at Northwestern.

Comment: @dismalscience that's what I'm looking for actually! I just find myself overwhelmed, and feeling scattered with looking around the net and just reading and bookmarking web pages that I find informative. Thanks for the advice!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you were to read only introductory book in econonomics:
[Economics: The User's Guide by Ha-Joon Chang.](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0718197038)
It explains all basics concepts in economics, and the differences between the main school of thoughts. It is quite easy to read, it is not a textbook.

For an overview of financial markets:
[Capital Ideas](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0471731749), and [Capital Ideas Evolving](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0470452498) by Peter L. Bernstein

For your interest in electricity:
[The Grid: A Journey Through the Heart of Our Electrified World](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/030910260X) by Phillip F. Schewe, very interesting on how the grid came to be.

[Smart Grid: Integrating Renewable, Distributed & Efficient Energy](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B005VNUPO2)
by Fereidoon P. Sioshansi (Editor), Sioshansi is a reference in Smart Grid and the paradigm change from consumer to prosumer.

Renewable Economics: How to compare the costs of different technologies:
[Energy Technologies and Economics](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/3319082248)